# What should I use for a 3.3 voltage reference that sinks maximum of 1mA?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-reference, reference, current-sink

I am in search for stable and precise 3.3 voltage reference IC. I am using it for the temperature sensor application which only sinks 1mA at max. Can someone suggest me a best component/IC for this type of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that *you* mean by "precision", but the [LT1461CCS8-3.3](http://www.linear.com/docs/1342) is pretty good (0.08% tolerance and 12ppm/°C maximum drift). It's a series reference that can supply 1mA easily.

If you want cheap, use a [TL431](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/TL431-D.PDF) and three resistors (1% + resistor tolerance, 50ppm/°C typical drift).

Answer (score 1):

you describe a problem - MAXIMUM 1mA. This suggests that you have a current limiting function. Is that needed? For what purpose? If no current limit is needed the TL431 is probably the lowest cost solution.

Comment: I meant I only need to sink maximum of 1 mA of current from that reference voltage. I don't need more current than 1mA out of that 3.3 Voltage reference. it is alright to have a voltage reference that is capable of providing more than 1mA before it strats to drop its voltage. I assumede that voltage reference become less precisive (more ppm) if it has a wider range of output current i.e up to 100 mA. What i want is less tolerable voltage reference. the current spec is just to help finding a good voltage reference. but yes TL431 could possible work. as its cheap!!